# HTML for below image

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, html

How to put image inside another image. Currently I am using below code in html file in lwc but the problem is record id is coming inside the 2nd image.:

```
  <div>
      <img src={backGround} style="position: relative;top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 1;">
      <img src={Logo} style="position:absolute; top: 110px; left: 10px; z-index: 3; border-radius: 50%;"/>
  </div>

  <div>
      record id:{recordId}
  </div> 
  
</lightning-card>
```

Sample UI:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see this article:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp

The key is to use

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 8px;
left: 16px;
```

in css inline or in separate file and then play with the position.
See example below:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
.container { position:relative; }
.imgA1 { position:absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 1; } 
.imgB1 { position:absolute; top: 70px; left: 100px; z-index: 3; } 
</style>

<div class="container">
<img class="imgA1" src="image1.png">
<img class="imgB1" src="image2.png">
</div>
```

Please read the answer carefully then try this code in some online HTML fiddler:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
.container { position:relative; }
.big { position:absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 1; }
.small { position:absolute; top: 1910px; left: 100px; z-index: 3; border-radius: 50%;} 

</style>

<div class="container">
<img class="big" src="https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C4D1BAQEhvgQlkIlFUQ/company-background_10000/0/1609775466074?e=1609948800&v=beta&t=gxVnP62nBuew2HBwenPQfFpfy2aqQXoUZRFM4synIZo">
<img class="small" src="https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQFx332BDosXcg/company-logo_200_200/0/1600185685242?e=1617840000&v=beta&t=bQgG3NJHlT5rnZZz11P9RVHH-UVMzCOswBPgmRYA7lI">
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: also take a look at the attribute "z-index: 1;" which will also probably help you.

Comment: also, when using `position:absolute`, you probably want to have a container which has `position:relative` thus making the absolute positioning of the child relative to that container.

Comment: Thank you but my requirement is different. The top portion will have an image and the round circle will also have another image. just like linkdin profile examle: https://www.linkedin.com/company/facebook/

Comment: This structure should be able to meet those requirements. You can use border-radius on the second image to make it round, and of course tweak the positioning as you need, but this should work.

Comment: Please see updated answer!

Comment: Hi Boris, Thanks! I have used the similar thing but the reocrd id is coming inside the 1st div. I am not able to move it downside. <template>
    <lightning-card>
  
      <div>
          <img src={backGround} style="position: relative;top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 1;">
          <img src={Logo} style="position:absolute; top: 110px; left: 10px; z-index: 3; border-radius: 50%;"/>
      </div>
    
      <div>
          record id:{recordId}
      </div> 
      
    </lightning-card>  
  </template>

Comment: In the snippet that you provided I do not see CSS for the container <div> .container { position:relative; }. If this does not solve the issue I think there is a big chance that <lightning-card> is bringing a lot of CSS attributes that might overwrite your CSS so please use !important; to make sure your CSS is not overwritten or last posible solution could be not using <lightning-card>